# How to update VUE JS dynamic menu item params based on updated route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my application I have dropdown option on the TOP navbar which will change the URL with `token` params. Like:

```
<b-form inline>
    <v-select
        v-model="selectedItem"
        label="title"
        :options="option" @input="chooseProject"
    />
    <b-button
    v-ripple.400="'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)'"
    variant="primary"
    class="ml-3"
    v-b-modal.modal-lg
>

chooseProject(e) {
    let token = this.extractFirstText( e.title );
    let projectName = e.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, '');
    let userId = this.projects.user_id;
    let store = [];
    
    store[0] = projectName;
    store[1] = token;
    this.$router.push('/dashboard/'+token );
    localStorage.setItem( 'lastProjectToken_'+userId,  JSON.stringify(store) );
},
```

Here, You can see that I am redirecting to **new route** usign this code:

> this.$router.push('/dashboard/'+token );

Now, I have a navbar list on the left side. I want to link this navbar item/s to that **new route**.

To do that, I am using this:

```
let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
let userId = userData.id;
let getTokenData = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("lastProjectToken_" + userId)
);
let token = getTokenData[1];

import router from "@/router";
let token3 = router.history.current.params.token;
let params = window.location.href;
let split = params.split("/");
let tokenFromUrl = split[4];

// console.log(tokenFromUrl);
// console.log(split);
// console.log(token);
// console.log(token3);

export default [
    {
        header: "Projects",
    },
    {
        title: "Import",
        route: {
            name: "project-import",
            params: { token: token },
        },
        icon: "SettingsIcon",
    },
];
```

Now, on first page load this **Import** nav item is showing this link:

http://localhost:3000/project/import/view/44-5347-3744-972

which is correct BUT when the Router is changes by selecting the dropdown then this nav item is not updating.

Is there any way to fix it?

**Update:**

**LayoutVertical.vue file:**

```
<template>
  <layout-vertical :nav-menu-items="navMenuItems">

    <router-view />

    <app-customizer
      v-if="showCustomizer"
      slot="customizer"
    />

  </layout-vertical>
</template>

<script>
import LayoutVertical from '@core/layouts/layout-vertical/LayoutVertical.vue'
import AppCustomizer from '@core/layouts/components/app-customizer/AppCustomizer.vue'
import { $themeConfig } from '@themeConfig'
import navMenuItems from '@/navigation/vertical'

export default {
  components: {
    AppCustomizer,
    LayoutVertical,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showCustomizer: $themeConfig.layout.customizer,
      navMenuItems,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

You can see that nav items is coming from `import navMenuItems from '@/navigation/vertical'`. This file contain this code:

```
import project from './project'
import dashboard from './dashboard'
import appsAndPages from './apps-and-pages'
import others from './others'
import chartsAndMaps from './charts-and-maps'
import uiElements from './ui-elements'
import formAndTable from './forms-and-table'

// Array of sections
export default [...project,...dashboard, ...appsAndPages, ...uiElements, ...formAndTable, ...chartsAndMaps, ...others]
```

Here the **Import** menu item is coming from `import project from './project'`

Comment: `I am using this` ... where are you using it and how are you using it? that exports what was read from localStorage, and is never going to change what it exports

Comment: Please check this code: https://github.com/razvypp/FeedParserProject/blob/main/resources/js/src/%40core/layouts/layout-vertical/LayoutVertical.vue. Here the menu items is coming from a js file using this `navMenuItems`

Comment: no, post the code you want help with in the question - rather than a link to a non-existant page - but for a start, I'd expect some `reactive` export

Comment: It' used in this file: import project from './project' and that file contain this code code: https://codeshare.io/wnxrEK